# A hard to understand paragraph

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, comprehension

How can the bolded part of the following text be expressed in the simple language?

> While the principals are a cut above this level of qualification **the incompetence of
> the American government to do business requires a rethinking on our part of why there
> have been so many frustrating failures to deliver on their part.**

Comment: The _of why_ part sounds iffy to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it amounts to being a request for editorial/writing advice about a specific block of text rather than a question of broad interest about a particular topic of English language or usage. In other words, it is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a critique rather than a solution

1. There are too many (potential) clauses in the sentence. Target each sentence to make one point, and one point only.
2. The "rethinking on our part" is vague. What rethinking is required? Or alternatively, what was the thinking or expectation going in, and what should have been the thinking/expectation in hindsight?
3. "On their part" should not be required once you are clear on 2.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase it as:

> The American government’s incompetence at business requires us to rethink why they’ve had so many frustrating failures.

It’s still a fairly complex sentence, but I can at least understand it now on the first pass rather than get halfway through, back up and read it again slowly.